# How to add a sibling element in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add multiple 'stop' elements like this:
defs
lineargradient
stop
stop
stop
stop

This is my code

```
 newSlice.append('defs')
    .append('linearGradient')           
    .append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red")
    .enter() 
    .append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red")
    .enter() ....... so on
```

But this creates only one stop element. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it up like this:

```
const grad = newSlice.append('defs')
    .append('linearGradient');

const stop1 = grad.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red");

const stop2 = grad.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red");
```

Then you have a variable for your gradient and each stop for access later on if you need eg:

```
stop2.attr("offset", "50%")
```